# Is there a way to know that a user clicked on the verification link?

Tags: firebase-authentication

Here's the code I'm using to send a verification email (taken from the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#send_a_user_a_verification_email))

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

`User` object has `emailVerified` property. It doesn't change when user clicks the link in the mail. It only updates on re-login.
Is there a way for an app to know that a user sucessfully verified their address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no client-side callback that triggers when the user clicks the verification link.

We've seen a feature request to trigger Cloud Functions when a user verifies their email address, but no updates on whether/when that will come. (Also see: [Cloud Functions for Firebase - action on email verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503377/cloud-functions-for-firebase-action-on-email-verified))

The best I can think of now is to call [`User.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) occasionally to get the updated properties.

Comment: sir, that's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Tiny dealbreaker, and these add up. Why not add this functionality, the whole point of firebase/firestore is to be reactive. Just discovered this for myself.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a continueUrl when sending an email verification to redirect back to your app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'https://www.example.com/?email=' + 
       firebase.auth().currentUser.email
};
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent.
  });
```

This will show a continue button after verification. You can use it to go back to the app or to some page where you can notify the original page via real time database of the verification.

Comment: This is so perfect! I have no idea why this is not the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure whether the user clicked on the verification link by trying to get the user id for the current user from Firebase, when it's empty, then this means that the user clicked on verification link and a new user has been created.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
if(!mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals("")){
// the user clicked on the verification link.
// a new user has been created.
}
else{
// the user didn't click on the verification link.
// No user created.
}
```