# Firebase authentication: click custom action link not verify email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I've been using Authenticate for Web service. I sent the  email verification link to the signup email with a custom action link. I'd like to redirect the user to home page when he clicks the link. Even when the link is clicked, `emailVerified` still got false.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    console.log("verified", user.emailVerified); //false

    auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
      console.log("after reload", auth.currentUser.emailVerified); // false
    });

  } else {
    console.log("no user signed in");
  }
});
```

Though it's not a problem with the default link Firebase provides.

Comment: The click on the email verification link happens in the user's inbox, so it is not visible to your app. If you want the user's profile in your app to be updated, you will have to [force a refresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938037/is-there-a-way-to-know-that-a-user-clicked-on-the-verification-link

Comment: Hello, it's not about refreshing. I know that kind of problem which we can fix by many ways such as using an observer like `onAuthStateChanged` or doing `reload` like you suggested. For this, it never updated `emailVerified` with the custom link. To be clear, default link still works.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate I can reopen. But at this point I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Are you saying that your user profile still shows the user as unverified even after you force a reload? If so, can you show the code for how you test that?

Comment: I edited so you can see the code from my question. I am sure that the email is not verified when the user clicked the link. Somehow it's like firebase won't do two works in the same line. Either by using the default action link, email is verified, or a custom link will only lead the user to that link not verifying the email.