# Firebase SendEmailVerification in Xamarin : how to handle this in App?

Tags: firebase, authentication, xamarin, verification

I am trying to use email verification in my Xamarin/Firebase app.
I currently have:

```
using (var actionCode = ActionCodeSettings.NewBuilder()
                       .SetHandleCodeInApp(true).Build()) {
      await user.SendEmailVerification(actionCode);
}
```

This properly sends a verification email.

What I don't know is how to specify a callback in the app to catch user clicking on the verification link.

Any advice/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to know that a user clicked on the verification link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938037/is-there-a-way-to-know-that-a-user-clicked-on-the-verification-link)

Comment: Sort of.  It's still unclear to me what's the point of the SetHandleCodeInnApp option.  It seems to indicate that there is a way of handling the verification event in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's still unclear to me what's the point of the SetHandleCodeInnApp option. It seems to indicate that there is a way of handling the verification event in the app

Whether the email action link will be opened in a mobile app or a web link first. The default is false. When set to true, the action code link will be be sent as a Universal Link or Android App Link and will be opened by the app if installed. In the false case, the code will be sent to the web widget first and then on continue will redirect to the app if installed.

For more details, you could check the document. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/passing-state-in-email-actions