# Firebase functions.auth.UserRecord is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger a **Firebase** Function upon `emailVerified` is true in [auth.UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord) but the below code is throwing a `TypeError: functions.auth.UserRecord is not a function` error when deploying to **Firebase**.

Is it possible to listen for `emailVerified`?

I could trigger `onCreate` of user but the function is to be for creating customers in Stripe and I would prefer this only happen upon email verification.

The function for listening is

```
exports = module.exports = functions.auth
.UserRecord((uid, emailVerified) => {
  // isVerified
  if (emailVerified) {
    const cid = admin
      .database()
      .ref()
      .push().key;

    var customerObject = {
      id: cid,
      dateCreated: new Date(),
      dateModified: new Date()
    };

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .doc(`users/${uid}/billing/${cid}`)
      .set(customerObject);
  } else {
    // isNotVerified
    return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Firebase Authentication trigger for Cloud Functions that exists are `functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)` and `functions.auth.user().onDelete((user)`. There is no Cloud Functions trigger for email verification.

Also see:

- [Cloud Functions for Firebase - action on email verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503377/cloud-functions-for-firebase-action-on-email-verified)
- the [Cloud Functions documentation for Authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events).

Comment: And [onDelete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onDelete).

Comment: Thank you Frank and Doug. So the UserRecord (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord)  cannot be used? If so, the only method is to add to a database user record and listen for that?

Comment: Thank you that first link is very helpful.